# How much of the Earth's surface was covered with water during the Mesozoic?

Tags: climate-change, climate, temperature, paleoclimatology

When the Earth was at its warmest, and there were no ice caps at all, not even during the winter, and thermal expansion meant a certain amount of water took up more space, what ratio of Earth's surface was covered in water?

Also, how much more expansive was water back then? 5% or so?

Comment: keep in mind geologic effect can drastically change the amount of land covered without any change in sea level. There used to be a seaway through much of middle America that only drained do to tectonic uplift changing the actual height of the land.

Answer (score 2):

At that time there were large areas of shallow seas, so small differences in elevation could lead to large differences in water area. I doubt that the elevations are well enough known to estimate the area precisely.

https://dinosaurpictures.org/ancient-earth/#90

The coefficient of expansion of water is only $207 \times 10^{-6}/K$. 15 degrees would give 0.3%.